# Use ajax request to load sidebar

Tags: ajax, sidebar

For a project, i've to improve SEO perf and one of this optimization is to load the sidebar with an ajax request.

I've looking for this solution through the documentation, source code, plugins repository without success.

So i need your help and advices. Is it possible to do this ? If yes, what is the best way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test anything, but I imagine it would be something like this:

As you must include a `sidebar.php`, just include an empty `sidebar.php`, and leave the *real* one to the `sidebar-ajax.php`, for example.

To call the sidebar:

```
<?php get_template_part('sidebar'); ?>
```

And it should be something like this:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

In your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    /* load your js file in footer */
    wp_enqueue_script('theme-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your-js-file.js', false, false, true);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_sidebar', 'check_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_sidebar', 'check_ajax');
function check_ajax() {
    ?>
    get_template_part('sidebar-ajax');
    <?php
}
```

And in `your-js-file.js`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: location.href,
    data: { get_ajax_sidebar: 1 },
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#sidebar').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for belayted answer but your solution works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Error #1: get_template_part('sidebar-ajax'); is outside of php tags! It will never work!
Error #2: location.href will actually call loaded page itself and inject into the sidebar content, instead a proper path to the template file must be specified.